# Which design pattern should I use to handle multiple if conditions to get search result base on inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Can anyone suggest to me which design pattern should I use to handle multiple if conditions for a search function.

The search function takes the product's name, type, and location. In my handler, I handle the input by using if conditions as the example below.

```
if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(ProductName) && !string.isNullOrEmpty(ProductType))
{
    // Query product and return base on name and type.
    var product = database.product
                          .Where(x => x.productname == productname)
                          .Where(x => x.producttype == producttype)
                          .ToList()
} 
else if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(ProductName) 
         && !string.isNullOrEmpty(ProductType)
         && !string.isNullOrEmpty(ProductLocation))
{
    // Query product and return base on name and location.
    var product = database.product
                          .Where(x => x.productname == productname)
                          .Where(x => x.ProductLocation == ProductLocation)
                          .ToList()
}
```

So, I ended up having multiples if conditions in my handler. Code starts to get bigger and bigger. In the future, when I may have new types of input. Especially, each if condition will have the same query function and only where the condition is added or removed base on inputs.

Is there a better way to handle inputs and remove duplicated query function?

Comment: [Specification pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern)

Comment: [Specification pattern: C# implementation](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/specification-pattern-c-implementation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not design pattern but common way when using LINQ

```cs
var query = database.product.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productName))
   query = database.product.Where(x => x.productname == productname);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productType))
   query = database.product.Where(x => x.producttype == producttype);

var product = query.ToList();
```

Or via helper function:

```cs
public static class MyQueryableExtensions
{
    public staic IQueryble<T> WhereIf<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, bool condiion, Expression<Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (condition)
            source = source.Where(predicate);
        return source;
    }
}
```

```cs
var product = database.product
    .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productName), x => x.productname == productname)
    .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productType), x => x.producttype == producttype)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I mean when I have like 50 conditions I will end up making if condition 50 times. so is there a way to make it cleaner?

Comment: @TsubagiYoshino, updated answer. If it is still unclear, more details are needed.

Comment: @TsubagiYoshino With 50+ conditions you are better off using a search engine like Elasticsearch that has better indexing capabilities than a regular database.

Comment: Cheers. I'm not reaching 50 conditions yet just given the example of how my problem was.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works like a charm. Cheers :)