# Is there any trick to avoid double checks when constructing Where criteria conditionally?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I am wondering whether I can simplify my code below, especially the following 2 statements:

```cs
// Statement A
Expression<Func<Product, bool>>? criteria = p =>
    (id == null ? true : p.Id == id) &&
    (name == null ? true : p.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())) &&
    (maxPrice == null ? true : p.Price <= maxPrice);


// Statement B
if (id is null && name is null && maxPrice is null)
    criteria = null;
```

I am not happy with the statement B because of two reasons:

- I have to check again each parameter that has been checked in the statement A.
- It is prone to error (forgetting to check all parameters)

#### Attempt

The following does not compile because

> An expression tree cannot contain an assignment operator.

```
bool sign = false;
Criteria = p =>
    (id == null ? (sign = true) : p.Id == id) &&
    (name == null ? (sign = true) : p.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()))
;

if (sign == false)
    Criteria = null;
```

#### Question

Is there any way to make it much simpler and less prone to errors?
Any suggestions are always welcome.

```
static IQueryable<Product> Filter(this IQueryable<Product> products,
    int? id = null,
    string? name = null,
    decimal? maxPrice = null)
{
    Expression<Func<Product, bool>>? criteria = p =>
        (id == null ? true : p.Id == id) &&
        (name == null ? true : p.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())) &&
        (maxPrice == null ? true : p.Price <= maxPrice);


    if (id is null && name is null && maxPrice is null)
        criteria = null;

    if (criteria is null)
        return products;
    else
        return products.Where(criteria);
}
```

Comment: Really, EF Core and `this IEnumerable<Product> products`? You will load whole table - use `IQueryable`. What about [WhereIf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66932424/10646316)?

Comment: One thing I've seen done, though not in this case, is to check for your value or null, e.g.; this code `(id == null ? true : p.Id == id) &&` would become this code, `(p.Id == id || id == null) &&`. If an id is present then it is used in the criteria, if it's not then the fact that it's null means all id's are returned, effectively taking the id out of the criteria. This would also mean you could filter on fields provided and ignore those which are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the pretty standard pattern of dynamically adding `Where` based on presence of filtering conditions:

```
static IQueryable<Product> Filter(this IQueryable<Product> products,
    int? id = null,
    string? name = null,
    decimal? maxPrice = null)
{
    if (id is not null)
    {
        products = products.Where(p => p.Id == id);
    }

    if (name is not null)
    {
        products = products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));
    }

    if (maxPrice is not null)
    {
        products = products.Where(p => p.Price <= maxPrice);
    }

    return products;
}
```

Comment: But it is considered as less performant approach.

Comment: @RowanParkinson, how is this "less performant?" the query will be performed on the server in exactly the same way if you built it in a single `Where()` clause.

Comment: @RowanParkinson, this is VERY good performant, especially for EF Core.

Comment: @RowanParkinson - by whom? What measurements have you taken?

Comment: @RowanParkinson have you checked how less performant it is? If you are worried about barebone performance - EF Core probably is not the best choice.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I read it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664683/should-i-use-two-where-clauses-or-in-my-linq-query.

Comment: @RowanParkinson - even if you take that at face value, without assessing whether it is important to your use case, that's talking about LINQ to Objects, not EF LINQ.

Comment: @RowanParkinson that is more about LINQ-to-Objects and doubtful that in most cases it will have noticeable effect even there.

Comment: @RowanParkinson, don't mix `IEnumerable` with `IQueryable`. Both looks the same, but `IQueryable` gives ability to translate Expressions to the SQL. And in your case SQL Server will perform filtering effectively by yourself.

Comment: @RowanParkinson - if you seriously care about performance, set *goals*, write simple code, *measure* the performance and assess whether changes need to be made. Don't believe you can learn a single set of (in reality about 12 billion) rules for constructs you should/shouldn't use.

Comment: @RowanParkinson you can always check the generated SQL. Also even if it is not - the database engine potentially can do that too.

Comment: @RowanParkinson If you are *actually* worried about performance then you would fix the obvious performance issue here `p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())` should be `p => p.Name.Contains(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` if you are using Linq2Objects, or for Linq2SQL you can change the collation of the actual column and just use `p => p.Name.Contains(name)`

Comment: @Charlieface: Good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for null on the received parameters, if any are null make that bit of criteria true by checking for null, e.g. `(id == null || p.Id== id)` basically says give me all Id's that match the parameter id or if it's null then give me all parameter Ids.

```
static IQueryable<Product> Filter(this IQueryable<Product> products,
    int? id = null,
    string? name = null,
    decimal? maxPrice = null)
{
    Expression<Func<Product, bool>> criteria = p =>
        (id == null || p.Id== id) &&
        (name == null || p.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())) &&
        (maxPrice == null || p.Price <= maxPrice);

        return products.Where(criteria);
}
```

This also has the added benefit of making the parameters optional.

Comment: `products.Where(p => true)` is as efficient as  `products`?

Comment: I believe it is, but my focus was on simplifying your criteria logic to remove the need for the null checks.

Comment: @RowanParkinson no, `products.Where(p => true)` will not be as efficient as `products`. The question is how big is overhead - I think it should not be noticable in the real world scenario. Check the generated SQL, compare query plans and benchmark. That is the only way to figure out how something affects performance in YOUR concrete scenario.

Comment: Most of the people commenting here still live with their "classic" EF6 knowledge. EF Core from almost the very beginning performs constant predicate part elimination, so the resulting SQL will be *exactly* the same as the "traditional" conditional `Where` or custom `WhereIf` extensions suggested in other answer/comments.

Comment: @IvanStoev, that's true, but using such optimisations EF Core (not sure) should regenerate SQL every time when input parameters was changed. From my perspective it is worst case.

Comment: @GuruStron: I just checked the log, I found both `products.Where(p => true)` and `products`  produce the same SQL command info.

Comment: @IvanStoev no-op still should be faster than any op, that what I was referring in my comment about performance of `.Where(_ => true)` and EF still need to process the the expression. =)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv This is a normal optimization which is similar to nowadays modern SQL query  optimizers would do. The main benefit of doing it this way and not with chained `Where` or custom extensions is that this works in any part of the query tree, while others are applicable only for top level queryables (well, your custom extension could be made to work inside query tree, but with 3rd party packages that you like :-))

Comment: @GuruStron Are we really counting picoseconds? The main point is that this works in all type of queries at any level, while your approach works only for top level (see my previous comment) and only for `AND` conditions. Hence for me this is the "right" general approach for the problem in EF Core.

Comment: @IvanStoev _"Are we really counting picoseconds?"_ - of course no, that is why I wrote about it being noticable in my original comment =). Personally I prefer the less generic approach cause I find it simpler to read/understand. Unless it does not do the job of course.